# How do I install the Entity Framework on my build server?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

How do I install the Entity Framework on my build server? I only have MS Visual Studio Shell installed there and there is no Package Manager Console.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to install EntityFramework on your build server. EntityFramework is part of the BCL, so all you have to do is install .NET on your build server. Now if you need to use some extensions that are available through NuGet packages, all you need to do is to add reference to those packages in your project and then all the necessary assemblies will be part of the web application. Thus the web application is self-contained. All you have to do is to put them under source control so that the build server is able to retrieve them.

Answer (score 1):

Do one of the following

- Add the EF assemblies to source control so they can be downloaded on checkout
- Enable [nuget package restore](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages) and allow the build server access to the internet to download the packages.

Comment: Thanks Luke, I don't have that item in the context menu. What should I do to see it? Maybe is it something I can change manually in the solution file XML source code?

Comment: @Alberto you need to make sure you have nuget 1.6 or above installed for Visual Studio. this will enable the context menu. What it actually does is add in a pre-build step for your solution which runs a mini exe and downloads any packages that arent there, so its not really something you can do manually in the project file.